# Unix write command to message another user

Tags: unix, message-queue

I have some handheld scanners that i would like to send messages to (running Unix) and after using the write command to send a message to a handheld scanner(computer) to someone on the warehouse floor, the message stays on the screen (we are using AML M7220 scanners).  Does anyone know a way to either clear the screen or refresh the screen after the message session has ended.  I have tried to email AML and call AML tech support but they don't give a crap about responding to emails and when calling, it is not even a valid phone number.  AML needs to update their website!!

Answer (score 1):

There are many commands available to send the message to another user in the same network

1.mesg 
2.talk
3.write
4.wall 
these commands are used to send the message to another users

Answer (score 0):

`write` is a fairly low-level utility. It has no notion of the contents of the screen that is at the end of the remote terminal, and anything else that happens to be running on that terminal has no awareness that its screen has just been polluted by a `write` session. Actually UNIX ttys in general have no notion of what's being on displayed on them (they are more or less just character streams).

You cannot clear the screen at the end of a `write` session because the only way you could possibly do it would be to pass a terminal-clearing terminal emulation sequence through the `write` session and (modern) `write` won't let you do that (it will escape it).

You cannot repaint the remote terminal's screen if some kind of full screen application happens to be running because there is no way to ask that application to do that.